# Filter network requests by content in FF/Chrome

Tags: graphql, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools, network-traffic

Is there a way to filter the network requests in FireFox or Chrome's developer tools, by content?

My issue is that there are many requests to a `/graphql` endpoint, that all have the same URL and type. I'd love to be able to filter for the specific request type (specified in the JSON payload), in order to easily how many requests of a given type are happening and when.

Is this possible?

Comment: [No](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#filter), but you can do it yourself in [devtools-on-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UI.panels.network).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: See the answers I've linked (e.g. [this one](/a/55186353/)): you can extend devtools with your own js code.

Comment: There are GraphQL developer tools extensions already built for Chrome, ex: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/developer-tooling/

Comment: Thanks @MichelFloyd, that's actually incredibly helpful. The two best ones for seem to be Querio and GraphQL Network Inspector.